# My code doesn't Enter the if loop to Enter Data unto my SD Card, Why it that?

Tags: arduino

I am Not understanding why my code isn't writing to my SD Card. I have tried various other methods to get my data on the card. The code isn't entering my IF loop at the bottom of the page. Could it be that i have entered the wrong pin to get the data from? I am using pins RX3 15 on the Arduino mega to get data? Would that pin be considered pin 63? I looked at a diagram online and that's what was said.

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
File mySensorData;
int chipSelect = 63; 


String inputstring = "";                              //a string to hold incoming data from the PC
String sensorstring = "";                             //a string to hold the data from the Atlas Scientific product
boolean input_string_complete = false;                //have we received all the data from the PC
boolean sensor_string_complete = false;               //have we received all the data from the Atlas Scientific product


void setup() {    //set up the hardware
  SD.begin(chipSelect);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);                                 //set baud rate for the hardware serial port_0 to 9600
  Serial3.begin(9600);                                //set baud rate for software serial port_3 to 9600
  inputstring.reserve(10);                            //set aside some bytes for receiving data from the PC
  sensorstring.reserve(30);                           //set aside some bytes for receiving data from Atlas Scientific product
}


void serialEvent() {                                  //if the hardware serial port_0 receives a char
  inputstring = Serial.readStringUntil(13);           //read the string until we see a <CR>
  input_string_complete = true;                       //set the flag used to tell if we have received a completed string from the PC
}


void serialEvent3() {                                 //if the hardware serial port_3 receives a char
  sensorstring = Serial3.readStringUntil(13);         //read the string until we see a <CR>
  sensor_string_complete = true;                      //set the flag used to tell if we have received a completed string from the PC
}


void loop() {                                         //here we go...


  if (input_string_complete == true) {                //if a string from the PC has been received in its entirety
    Serial3.print(inputstring);                       //send that string to the Atlas Scientific product
    Serial3.print('\r');                              //add a <CR> to the end of the string
    inputstring = "";                                 //clear the string
    input_string_complete = false;                    //reset the flag used to tell if we have received a completed string from the PC
  }

  if (sensor_string_complete == true) {               //if a string from the Atlas Scientific product has been received in its entirety
    if (isdigit(sensorstring[0]) == false) {          //if the first character in the string is a digit
      Serial.println(sensorstring);                   //send that string to the PC's serial monitor
    }
    else                                              //if the first character in the string is NOT a digit
    {
      print_EC_data();                                //then call this function
    }
    sensorstring = "";                                //clear the string
    sensor_string_complete = false;                   //reset the flag used to tell if we have received a completed string from the Atlas Scientific product
  }
}


void print_EC_data(void) {                            //this function will pars the string

  char sensorstring_array[30];                        //we make a char array
  char *EC;                                           //char pointer used in string parsing
  char *TDS;                                          //char pointer used in string parsing
  char *SAL;                                          //char pointer used in string parsing
  char *GRAV;                                         //char pointer used in string parsing
  float f_ec;                                         //used to hold a floating point number that is the EC

  sensorstring.toCharArray(sensorstring_array, 30);   //convert the string to a char array
  EC = strtok(sensorstring_array, ",");               //let's pars the array at each comma
  TDS = strtok(NULL, ",");                            //let's pars the array at each comma
  SAL = strtok(NULL, ",");                            //let's pars the array at each comma
  GRAV = strtok(NULL, ",");                           //let's pars the array at each comma

if(mySensorData){
  Serial.print("EC:");                                //we now print each value we parsed separately
  Serial.println(EC);                                 //this is the EC value

  Serial.print("TDS:");                               //we now print each value we parsed separately
  Serial.println(TDS);                                //this is the TDS value

  Serial.print("SAL:");                               //we now print each value we parsed separately
  Serial.println(SAL);                                //this is the salinity value

  Serial.print("GRAV:");                              //we now print each value we parsed separately
  Serial.println(GRAV);                               //this is the specific gravity
  Serial.println();                                   //this just makes the output easier to read


mySensorData= SD.open("CPData", FILE_WRITE);
mySensorData.print(EC);
mySensorData.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to open a file before ```if (mySensorData)```?

Comment: I don't think so. Are you saying my put [mySensorData= SD.open("CPData", FILE_WRITE);]  before [if (mySensorData)]?

Comment: If you don't call ```mySensorData = SD.open();```, ```mySensorData``` may be NULL. If NULL, ```if(mySensorData)``` always evaluates to ```false```.

Comment: Hope i'm understanding you, but i did call `mySensorData= SD.open("CPData.txt", FILE_WRITE);`  Its closer to the bottom of the code.

Comment: ```mySensorData= SD.open("CPData.txt", FILE_WRITE);``` is in an if statement ```if(mySensorData)```.  If ```mySensorData``` is NULL at the if statement, it always evaluates to ```false```. Everything inside the if statement won't get executed.

Comment: I took `mySensorData= SD.open("CPData.txt", FILE_WRITE);` out of the if statment and put it above `if(mySensorData)` and i'm still coming up blank

Comment: What about ```Serial.print()``` inside the if statement? Do they get printed?

Comment: No they don't get printed

Comment: That means you failed to open a file. maybe you need to add an extension. Sounds like Arduino is picky on naming. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47664817/sd-open-returns-true-but-does-not-create-a-file

Comment: "The code isn't entering my IF loop at the bottom of the page" Your question is then "Why is (mySensorData==0) ?" Because the file was not opened yet.